# How to prevent Entity Framework from adding referenced objects to database on SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have quite a simple situation. I've got 3 objects:

- an object called `TrainingConsultant` which is not yet saved to the database
- an object called `Training` which was recently saved to the database and its `EntityState` is `Detatched`.
- an object called `Consultant` which was recently loaded the from database and its `EntityState` is `Detatched`.

I need to save the `TrainingConsultant` object with referenced `Consultant` and `Training`, so that in the database all the required fields and foreign keys are filled in properly.

The problem is that until I call `context.TrainingConsultants.AddObject(trainingConsultant);`, everything is in the `Detached` state. After that, both `training` and `consultant` have their `EntityState` changed to `Added`, so `context.SaveChanges()` tries to add both `training` and `consultant` to the database before adding `traingingConsultant`. It fails because `Consultant` already exists in the database, so does `consultant`.

How can I fix this so both `Consultant` and `Training` won't get saved but still get referenced? Keep in mind that I am assigning those 2 referenced objects somewhere else in code:

```
trainingConsultant.Training = training;
trainingConsultant.Consultant = consultant;
```

So when it comes to saving any changes would require me to save objects temporary, then set `TrainingConsultant.Training` and `TrainingConsultant.Consultant` to `null`?

```
using (var context = new Entity(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
{
    context.TrainingConsultants.AddObject(trainingConsultant);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just specify by ID rather than attaching an entity:

```
trainingConsultant.TrainingId = training.Id;
trainingConsultant.ConsultantId = consultant.Id;

context.TrainingConsultants.AddObject(trainingConsultant);
context.SaveChanges();
```

You can adjust as necessary to match your field/column names.

Comment: So basically I would need to go and null out Training, Consultant and then just attach ID's?

Comment: But it makes things inconvenient later on. It works, saved things to database but now I've got an object `trainingConsultant` that have null values in Consultant and Training fields. Anything that relies on those (like ObjectListView fails). So should I reatach them after save and always detatch them before save (just assigning ID's)?

Comment: Try refreshing the context after calling `SaveChanges()` by calling `context.TrainingConsultants.Load()`